# How to calculate the ISO week day using the ordinal day and the day of the week of the 1st of January?

Tags: c, date, math, iso, weekday

I need to calculate the ISO week day for a specific date. I've currently got functions that calculate the ordinal day, as well as a function which calculates the day of the 1st of January in every year, however, I now need a function which will calculate the ISO week day for any date.

I'm supposed to do this with the ordinal day, day of the week and modulo 7 arithmetic but i'm not exactly sure how to do it, for example, for the date Friday 26 September 2008, my ordinal day should be 270 (which it is) and my weekday number should be 5(Friday) which it isn't. I think i'm supposed to combine the two with modulo 7 arithmetic but i'm not exactly sure how.

I've tried doing 270 % 7 which gave me an answer of 4 but it should be 5. I'm not entirely sure how i'm supposed to put the two values together (if I even need to)

My code for the two functions:

```
int day_of_the_week(int year)
{
int week_day;
week_day = ((1 + 5 * ((year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year 
- 1) % 400) ) % 7);
if (week_day == 0) {
    week_day = 7;
}
return 0;
}


int calculate_ordinal_day(int day, int month, int year, int isyearleap) {
int ordinal_day;

if (month == 1) {
    return day;
}
if (month == 2) {
    return day + 31;
}

ordinal_day = myFloor(30.6 * month - 91.4) + day;
if (isyearleap == 1) {
    return ordinal_day + 60;
}
return ordinal_day + 59;
}
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that `Friday` should be `5`? You're doing modulo `7`, so the possible results are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `6`. `0` being first first day, `Monday`, and `6` the last day, `Sunday`. `Friday` is correctly numbered as `4`. If you want `Monday` to be `1` and `Sunday` to be `7` instead, just add `1` to the result.